# Not Able to run curl SDK man, or ruby from terminal

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, curl, openssl

I have been getting this error while running the below commands on my mac

curl somewebsite.com

Fullter upgrade

dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/curl
Reason: image not found

SDK commands and it give problem connecting to the internet

I have tried all the fixes I came across no of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few checks it turned out MacOS has it own version of curl that uses an older version of openssl. to solve the problem I added the blow to.bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig"
```